# Processing power and core allocation in VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, multi-core

I would like to know how if it is possible to harvest the full power of a CPU by allocating a lesser number of cores compared to the physical number of cores in a virtual machine.

What I mean is:

Let's say we have a server with **16 physical** cores (32 Threads).

If I create one single VM Machine and I make the virtual CPU have **8 virtual cores** will I be limited to the processing power of 8 physical cores or will the VM layer use enable the full use of the processing power or all 16 physical cores ?

How does this work in VM-Ware compared to Hyper-V ?

I know some VM-Ware users said that using virtual sockets or virtual cores does not impact the performance of the virtual machine, but is this also valid in this scenario ?
And is it the same in the case of Hyper-V  ?

Comment: This is explained in detail in this VMWare publication: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vmware-perfbest-practices-vsphere6-0-white-paper.pdf There unfortunately isn't a short answer that I could provide here. It depends on your exact VM configuration, CPU technology and how many VMs with how many vCPUs are running on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, not possible. Generally VM's distribute load to available cores - they do not change the way a core works. You will not magically end up with faster cores by using having less cores in a VM - waht happens is that you will in your example have 8 physical cores under full load, and 8 doing nothing.

Virtualization as commonly available is about splitting a machine to multiple VM's. There are some rare breeds that can combine computers to a more powerfull computer "transparently" (requiring very special network hardware). But nothing short from a full emulation would b able to combine cores - and I am not aware of any single virtualization approach even trying to go this route.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That means I'll really need SQL licenses for all physical cores of my servers if I want to harvest all processing power.

Comment: Yes. There is no way around it. You basically abuse virtualization - as I said, the current idea was ato slice a machine into smaller units, not to make it appear larger (which is REALLY hard, if even possible). Run mltiple smaller vm's on a big box ;) No way around your licensing.